Doing unsupervised anomaly detection on a dataset without any labels and without variable descriptions
I am trying to do unsupervised anomaly detection on a dataset with a dozen of variables. None of them have descriptions, and the dataset doesn't have any labels or class variable.
I have tried using a Robust scaler to fit and transform the data, and then fitting an Isolation Forest and Local outlier factor on the dataset, but when I try to visualize the results by doing a PCA on the data that has been scaled, I cannot really see anomalies or clear outliers in the visualization, but I'm not sure why. I've looked into some tutorials, and they follow the same steps as I did.
How can evaluate my models and visualize the outliers ? By plotting the anomalies in red they don't really seem to be far away or differs from the normal data point on a PCA plot.
Am I missing something or forgetting an important step before fitting the algorithm ?
